# How should I update a component and non-component from an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Sorry if the question is confusing but I am just getting started with React. Basically, I am looking to start adding individual components to an existing website. Currently, when the page loads there are a couple of AJAX requests that update different parts of the page with jQuery.

For example, I make an AJAX request that is called every 30 seconds to get AccountInfo and when it returns a response, I update two separate parts of the page, let's call them AccountPanel and SideBar.

**Question #1**

If I were to create a component for the AccountPanel, should I make the AJAX request when the component mounts and continue to use jQuery to update the SideBar in there?

**Question #2**

Or is it better to create components for both and pass the AJAX response as props?

```
ReactDOM.render(<AccountPanel  />, document.getElementById('accountPanel'));
ReactDOM.render(<SideBar />, document.getElementById('sideBar'));
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You have some jQuery plugin so you have to use jQuery? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you need some state container. To share state(in your case AccountInfo) between all of your components.

Personally, I recommend using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). Because this container is completely predictable.

In result you code will looks like:

```
//create redux store somehow

ReactDOM.render(<AccountPanel  store = {resuxStore}/>, document.getElementById('accountPanel'));
ReactDOM.render(<SideBar  store = {resuxStore}/>, document.getElementById('sideBar'));
```

Comment: I've been reading a lot on Redux. As we move more of the application to React, it will become more complex and a single source for the data is probably the best way to go.